# Exact expansion of functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Prove that for any twice differentiable function $f: {R}^n \to R$,

$f(y) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T (y-x)+ \frac{1}{2} (y-x)^T \nabla^2f(z)(y-x) $,
for some $z$ on the line segment $[x, y]$.
Note that it is not approximation, it is exact equality.

Comment: What is $F$...?

Comment: Thanks rlgordonma. That was a mistake. I corrected it. I meant $f$.

Comment: Referencing the proof is also helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a trick. Take $\gamma(t) = t y + (1 - t) x$. Let's think about the function $g(t) = f \circ \gamma(t)$: the Taylor expansion for this single-variable function about $t = 0$ looks like

$$
g(t) = g(0) + t g'(0) + \frac{t^2 }{2} g''(s)
$$
for some $s \in (0,t)$. Note that $g(1) = f \circ \gamma(1) = f(y), g(0) = f(x)$. The $g', g''$ terms can be found using the chain rule.

Comment: Interesting. Now the question is why do we have this Taylor EQUALITY for the single-variable function.

Comment: What you're referring to is a straightforward generalization of the mean value theorem; wikipedia has a few proofs on there, but if you want to do it yourself, you should try applying integration by parts to $f(x) - f(0) = \int_0^x f'(y) dy$. Then the remainder term will come out as $\int_0^x y f''(y) dy$: how can you use the intermediate value theorem to conclude?

Comment: @ABlumenthal Thanks. You mean $\gamma(t) = ty + (1-t)x$, not $tx+(1-t)y$, so $g(1)=f(y)$ and $g(0)=f(x)$, don't you?

Comment: @chan1142 Yes, I think I do. Thanks for the correction.